# Solution of the geodesic equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have the geodesic equations
$$ \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}-2\frac{1}{u}\frac{dx}{dt} \frac{du}{dt}=0;$$
$$\frac{d^2 u}{dt^2} + \frac{1}{u} \left [ \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right )^2 - \left(\frac{du}{dt} \right )^2 \right ]$$
-with the answer $x^2+u^2-ax=b.  $ a,b are constants.

But I don’t know how to solve it via differential equations or via Maple?
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You have a $y$ in your solution, but no $y$ in your problem. Where did this come from? Also, what is your second equation equal to? Please correct your problem to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Take a look at p. 92 of my differential geometry text (link in my profile). You mean $u$ instead of $y$, of course. And for everyone else, these are the equations for a geodesic in the hyperbolic plane (half-space model).

Comment: Thank you! I enjoyed the way you had solved the equation in your paper.